# Preserve SetPixel Changes made by C++ Program on Repaint

Tags: c++, repaint

I am writing a C++ program that uses `SetPixel()` to shift the contents of the screen down several pixels. The program is supposed to be a recreation of the visual effects of the well known [Melting Screen Worm](http://malware.wikia.com/wiki/MeltingScreen). Although the program works, I am running in to a problem when the screen is repainted. Whenever a repaint happens, the pixel shifts are lost. I understand that this is standard behavior for `SetPixel()`, but I would like to find a way to stop it, or at least reapply the pixel shifts after a repaint so that it appears as if the changes were never removed. How can I do this?

Comment: Create a bitmap and use it as a backbuffer then blit the bitmap during repaint.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What do you mean when you say "blit"? Also, is the bitmap just going to contain information on the pixel offsets or is it going to be an actual full image?

Comment: @DavidB: Look up BitBlt. You'd at least normally have it store a full image.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you, although I'm still confused. If I store a bitmap of the screen prior to when the repainting took place, wouldn't painting the bitmap just cover the updated screen's content? I want the screen content to be alter-able, while preserving the pixel offset.

Comment: Are you setting pixels in *your window* or the entire screen?

Comment: @DavidB: Typically you'll start by copying the area you care about to your bitmap. Then you'll modify your bitmap as needed. Then when you need to paint the screen, you'll copy from your bitmap to the screen. When you need to make further modifications, you don't draw them directly to the scree--you draw them to your bitmap, then blit it to the screen.

Comment: @immibis I am setting pixels for the entire screen.

Comment: @JerryCofin But how? I've been reading up on how to use `BitBlt` since making this post, but cannot figure out how to use it to achieve what I want.